# How to print X amount of names from a list without using a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, list

If you have a list of 50 names and you need to print names 0-7, how would you that without using foreach?
I tried

```
Console.WriteLine($"The people on the list are {names[0-7]}");
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, since you're turning a collection into a string then you need to join elements from that collection.  So you can start with something like this to display all of them:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The people on the list are {string.Join(", ", names)}");
```

(Syntax highlighting on this page suggests it's a syntax error, but it should work in actual C#.  The syntax highlighter here probably just doesn't support `$""` placeholders for C# yet.)

Given that, all you need from there is to filter down the collection.  If you're `using System.Linq` in your code then you can make use of [the `Take()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) to grab a given number of elements from the list:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The people on the list are {string.Join(", ", names.Take(7))}");
```

Comment: If a collection does not support `Take` extension method, you can sometimes add `.ToList()` before: `names.ToList().Take(7)`. There is also `Skip` to bypass some items to take for example names 10-17 (from 0): `names.Skip(10).Take(7)`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use David's answer of `Take()`, but here's another way using [List.CopyTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.copyto?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_CopyTo_System_Int32__0___System_Int32_System_Int32_):

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
Enumerable.Range(0, 50).ToList().ForEach(x => names.Add(x.ToString()));

string[] firstEightNames = new string[8];
names.CopyTo(0, firstEightNames, 0, firstEightNames.Length);
Console.WriteLine($"The people on the list are {string.Join(", ", firstEightNames)}");
```